# Invalid generation of input field's id and name attribute in Thymeleaf with JS

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I am encountering a very strange problem for which I can not find the cause. Simply put, when I am trying to update some previously given answers in my application in the update.html, then something generates random ids and random name values for one of my input fields and thus this specific data will not be sent to the backend.

Here is controller method for my update.html

```
 @GetMapping("/update/{questionFormId}/{appUserId}")
 public String updateAnswerFormCreatedByUser(@PathVariable long questionFormId, @PathVariable long appUserId, Model model) {
   log.info("GET answer-form/update/" + questionFormId + "/" + appUserId + " started");
   try {
     model.addAttribute("answerForm", answerFormService.createAnswerFormToUpdate(questionFormId, appUserId));
     log.info("GET answer-form/update/" + questionFormId + "/" + appUserId + " finished");
     return "answerform/update";
```

This is the class of the object that I am sending to the HTML

```
public class CreateAnswerFormDTO {
  private long questionFormId;
  private long answerFormId;
  private long appUserId;
  private List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();
  private List<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<>();

  public CreateAnswerFormDTO() {
  }
// with other constructors and getters/setters
```

The Question class

```
// I have four different types of questions (text, checkbox, radio and scale(radio but with numbers) 
//and I store them in the same table and they have some different class variables as well)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "Question_Type")
@Where(clause="deleted=0")
public class Question implements Comparable<Question> {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private long id;
 @NotNull
 private String questionText;
 private int listPosition;
 private boolean deleted;

 @Transient
 private List<String> answersNotFilledOutByUser = new ArrayList<>();

 @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
 @JsonBackReference(value = "questionsQuestionForm")
 private QuestionForm questionForm;

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
 @JsonManagedReference("answersQuestion")
 private List<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<>();
// with constructors, getters and setters
```

My Answer class

```
public class Answer {
// I store the concrete answertexts provided by the users in the ActualAnswerText class, 
// because f.e. text questions or checkbox questions can have multiple answer texts"
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long id;

  private boolean deleted;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "answer", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
  @JsonManagedReference(value = "answersActualAnswerTexts") 
  private List<ActualAnswerText> actualAnswerTexts = new ArrayList<>();

  @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
  @JsonBackReference(value = "answersAnswerform")
  private AnswerForm answerForm;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
  @JsonBackReference("answersQuestion")
  private Question question;
// with constructors, getters and setters
```

My update html

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Update Answerform</title>
  <link th:replace="fragments/navbar.html :: bootstrap-link">
  <link th:replace="fragments/navbar.html :: css">
</head>
<body>
<script th:src="@{/js/renderanswerform.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<header th:replace="fragments/navbar.html :: navbar"></header>
<div th:replace="fragments/messages.html :: error"></div>
<h1>Update your answerform</h1> 
<form id="answerform" method="post"
      th:action="@{|/answer-form/update/${answerForm.answerFormId}/${answerForm.appUserId}|}">
  <tr th:each="question, iterStat : ${answerForm.questions}">
    <p th:text="${question.questionText}"></p>  
<!--Rendering the question's text-->
    <div>
      <th:block th:switch="${question.getDiscriminatorValue()}"> 
<!--checking what questiontype the current question belongs to-->

        <div th:case="'CheckBoxQuestion'">
                        <span th:each="questionTextPossibility, list: ${question.questionTextPossibilities}">
                            <label th:text="${questionTextPossibility.answerText}"></label>  <!--Displaying the possible answertext value-->
                          <!-- I use th:field to prefill-->
                          <!-- I use th:name to make it available on the backend-->
                          <!-- I use th:value to set what value will be sent to the backend when clicking on this checkbox-->
                            <input
                                th:field="${answerForm.answers[__${iterStat.index}__].actualAnswerTexts[__${list.index}__].answerText}"
                                th:name="answers[__${iterStat.index}__].actualAnswerTexts[__${list.index}__].answerText"
                                th:value="${questionTextPossibility.answerText}"
                                type="checkbox">
                        </span>
        </div>
        <div th:case="'RadioButtonQuestion'">
                        <span th:each="questionTextPossibility, list: ${question.questionTextPossibilities}">
                            <label th:text="${questionTextPossibility.answerText}"></label>

                   <input th:field="${answerForm.answers[__${iterStat.index}__].actualAnswerTexts[0].answerText}"
                          th:name="answers[__${iterStat.index}__].actualAnswerTexts[0].answerText"
                          th:value="${questionTextPossibility.answerText}"
                          type="radio">
                        </span>
        </div>

        <div th:case="'ScaleQuestion'">
          <th:block th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(1, question.scale)}">
 <!-- Scale question generates radio button with numbers until the scale attribute of ScaleQuestion class-->
            <label th:text="${i}"></label>
            <input th:field="${answerForm.questions[__${iterStat.index}__].answers[0].actualAnswerTexts[0].answerText}"
                   th:name="answers[__${iterStat.index}__].actualAnswerTexts[0].answerText"
                   th:value="${i}"
                   type="radio">
          </th:block>
        </div>

        <div th:case="'TextQuestion'" th:id="|textquestioncreate[__${iterStat.index}__]|">
          <!--With TextQuestion users can provided more than one answer.
 f.e What are the best movies? They can generate more than one input fields to provide answers -->
                 <span th:id="|answers[__${iterStat.index}__]|">
                   <span
                       th:each="actualAnswerText, list: ${answerForm.answers[__${iterStat.index}__].actualAnswerTexts}">

                     <input
                         th:field="${answerForm.answers[__${iterStat.index}__].actualAnswerTexts[__${list.index}__].answerText}"
                         th:name="answers[__${iterStat.index}__].actualAnswerTexts[__${list.index}__].answerText"
                         type="text">
                    </span>
                   </span>

          <script th:inline="javascript"> 
 <!-- This js code creates the buttons that enable the adding of new input fields,
 finishing given question and re-enabling modification-->
              /*<![CDATA[*/
              renderQuestionText(/*[[${iterStat.index}]]*/)
              /*]]>*/
              /*<![CDATA[*/
              resetForCreatingTextQuestion()
              /*]]>*/
          </script>
        </div>
      </th:block>
    </div>
  </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Lastly, my renderanswerform.js file

```
// I haven't listed all the functions because some are just for creating
// finish, submit, reset and re-enable buttons
var actualAnswerIndexForTextQuestion = 0;
var buttonIndexToEnable = 0;
var currentTextAnswerIndex = 0;
var numberOfInputFieldsCreated = 0;
var hasInputfieldsCreated = false;

window.onload = function WindowLoad(event) {
    createValidateResetAndSubmitButtons();
}

function renderQuestionText(index) {
    if (!hasInputfieldsCreated) {
        let container = document.getElementById("textquestioncreate[" + index + "]");
        container.appendChild(createTextQuestionInput(index));
        hasInputfieldsCreated = true;
    }
}

function renderQuestionTextForCreate(index) {
    let container = document.getElementById("textquestioncreate[" + index + "]");
    container.appendChild(createTextQuestionInput(index));
    hasInputfieldsCreated = true;
}


function createTextQuestionInput(index) {
    let container = document.getElementById("answers[" + index + "]");
    let anotherInputButton = createAnotherInputButton(index);
    anotherInputButton.disabled = true;
    anotherInputButton.id = "textanswerbutton" + currentTextAnswerIndex;
    let finishButton = createFinishButtonForTextAnswer(currentTextAnswerIndex);

    let reEnableButton = createReenableButton(currentTextAnswerIndex);

    container.appendChild(anotherInputButton);
    container.appendChild(finishButton);
    container.appendChild(reEnableButton);
    enableDisableFinishAndAddAnotherTextFieldButtons();
    currentTextAnswerIndex++;
    return container;
}

function createAnotherInputButton(index) {
    let anotherInputButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    anotherInputButton.id = "anotherinputbutton" + index;
    anotherInputButton.textContent = "Create another input field";
    anotherInputButton.className = "buttonsToDisableEnable";
    anotherInputButton.type = "button";
    anotherInputButton.addEventListener("click", () => createAnotherInputField(index));
    return anotherInputButton;
}

function createAnotherInputField(index) {
    let elementId = "answers[" + index + "]";
    let container = document.getElementById(elementId);
    let numberOfInputFieldsInContainer = container.getElementsByTagName('INPUT').length
    let input = document.createElement("INPUT");
    numberOfInputFieldsCreated++;
    input.id = "textanswer" + currentTextAnswerIndex;
    actualAnswerIndexForTextQuestion++;
    input.name = "answers" + "[" + index + "].actualAnswerTexts[" + numberOfInputFieldsInContainer + "].answerText";
    container.insertBefore(input, document.getElementById("textanswerbutton" + buttonIndexToEnable));
}
```

Instead of having the proper name attributes at the ScaleQuestion input, I see the following when inspecting it in the browser. I have provided any id nowhere in the code and the name attribute shouldn't contain "question0.answers0" at the beginning, only answers[0].
ScaleQuestion in HTML when starting the app (Incorrect)

```
<div>
          
            <label>1</label>
            <input name="questions[2].answers[0].actualAnswerTexts[0].answerText" value="1" type="radio" id="questions2.answers0.actualAnswerTexts0.answerText1">
          
            <label>2</label>
            <input name="questions[2].answers[0].actualAnswerTexts[0].answerText" value="2" type="radio" id="questions2.answers0.actualAnswerTexts0.answerText2">
          
            <label>3</label>
            <input name="questions[2].answers[0].actualAnswerTexts[0].answerText" value="3" type="radio" id="questions2.answers0.actualAnswerTexts0.answerText3">
          
            <label>4</label>
            <input name="questions[2].answers[0].actualAnswerTexts[0].answerText" value="4" type="radio" id="questions2.answers0.actualAnswerTexts0.answerText4">
          
            <label>5</label>
            <input name="questions[2].answers[0].actualAnswerTexts[0].answerText" value="5" type="radio" id="questions2.answers0.actualAnswerTexts0.answerText5">
          
            <label>6</label>
            <input name="questions[2].answers[0].actualAnswerTexts[0].answerText" value="6" type="radio" id="questions2.answers0.actualAnswerTexts0.answerText6">
          
            <label>7</label>
            <input name="questions[2].answers[0].actualAnswerTexts[0].answerText" value="7" type="radio" id="questions2.answers0.actualAnswerTexts0.answerText7">
          
            <label>8</label>
            <input name="questions[2].answers[0].actualAnswerTexts[0].answerText" value="8" type="radio" id="questions2.answers0.actualAnswerTexts0.answerText8">
          
        </div>
```

RadioButton Question (Correct):

```
<span>
                           <label>radio1</label>

                  <input name="answers[0].actualAnswerTexts[0].answerText" value="radio1" type="radio" id="answers0.actualAnswerTexts0.answerText1">
                       </span>
```

What I have tried so far:

- Restarting Intellij with Invalidate caches
- Remove caches from Browser
- Use different browser
- Copy content to a different html file and reference that one from the controller
- Cry

My guess is that somehow some previous state of the js code interferes (because before that all the input fields were generated in js), but I can not see how or where.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: `th:field` generates the `name`, `id`, and `value` of the field it's on.  If you don't want those autogenerated by Thymeleaf, you shouldn't use it.  (In addition, `Values for th:field attributes must be selection expressions *{...}` and shouldn't be normal `${...}` expressions. Also... if you use `th:field` you are supposed to defined a `th:object` on your form...)

Comment: @Metroids You are right, however, what should one do when sending from the Controller's GET method an object to the HTML that should be rendered there so that  it can be modified by the user. But afterwards when from the same HTML via form a different object should be sent and will be received at the Controller's POST method and thus I would need for this different field names
And unfortunately even if th:field generates name, id and value, but this still doesn't explain why this id and name was generated by ScaleQuesiton and why not  by the RadioButtonQuestion option
Thanks for the help!